# Exception while deserializing XML wtih DataContractSerializer in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datacontractserializer

I have the following snippet written in .net core:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace BugTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var xml = @"<PingDataConfirmation  xmlns=""http://mycompany.com/MyProduct/Operations"">
        <SourceGuid>88c02aba-f78c-4749-8665-0caddee08b8a</SourceGuid>
        <Guid>88c02aba-f78c-4749-8665-0caddee08b8a</Guid>
        <CreationTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreationTime>
      </PingDataConfirmation>";

            const int buffSize = 1000000;

            int bytes = 0;
            int chars = 0;
            byte[] result = new byte[buffSize];
            bool compl;
            Encoding.UTF8.GetEncoder().Convert(xml.ToCharArray(), 0, xml.Length, result, 0, buffSize, true, out chars, out bytes, out compl);

            var xmlReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(result, 0, bytes, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
            var sr = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(PingDataConfirmation));
            var deserialized = sr.ReadObject(xmlReader);
        }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/MyProduct/Operations")]
    public class PingDataConfirmation
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string SourceGuid { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string Guid { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It throws exception:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1
>   position 86. 'Element' 'SourceGuid' from namespace
>   'http://mycompany.com/MyProduct/Operations' is not expected. Expecting
>   element 'CreationTime'

So it looks like, DataContractSerialized has missed one of the properties.

So, may it be bug in .net core implementation of DataContractSerializer? Is there any possiblity to debug interior to see why it happens?

CSPROJ:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="*" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

.net core:

```
1.0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your [data member order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order.aspx) is inconsistent with the order of elements in the XML.

From [Data Member Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-member-order):

> - If a data contract type is a part of an inheritance hierarchy, data members of its base types are always first in the order.
> - Next in order are the current type’s data members that do not have the Order property of the DataMemberAttribute attribute set, in
>     alphabetical order.
> - Next are any data members that have the Order property of the DataMemberAttribute attribute set. These are ordered by the value of
>     the `Order` property first and then alphabetically if there is more
>     than one member of a certain `Order` value. Order values may be
>     skipped.

And from [Data Contract Equivalence: Data Member Order and Data Contract equivalence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-equivalence#inheritance-interfaces-and-data-contract-equivalence):

> Keep in mind that the order of the data members must match and that
>   base type members precede derived type members in the order.

Thus either the order of elements in the XML must be alphabetical, or `DataMemberAttribute.Order` values must be specified that are consistent with the actual order of elements in the XML:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/MyProduct/Operations")]
public class PingDataConfirmation
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string SourceGuid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
    public string Guid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 3)]
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
}
```